# Setting up graphics cards on Razer Blade 2019 with Ubuntu 18.04 - Loading NVIDIA driver when needed

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-optimus

I would like to use the iGPU to manage the monitors and the dGPU for ML.

When I do `prime-select intel` the pc switches correctly to the intel GPU. Is use then `bbswitch` to turn ON and OFF the dGPU. I would like to be able to switch to the Intel GPU and use the dGPU for deep learning with TF or PyTorch. However, after having switched to the iGPU, `nvidia-smi` does not work and I cannot use the dGPU for deep learning.

I have an RTX 2080 MaxQ, Nvidia Drivers 440.44 and CUDA 10.2. What can I do to have two operating modalities such as:

- `powersave` mode: iGPU to manage screens and dGPU off.
- `work` mode: iGPU to manage screens and dGPU on to be used with TF or torch

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. Just install nvidia driver >=435.17 & Xorg >= 1.20.7 & uninstall bumblebee.

Ubuntu 19.04 and 18.04 officially support it. You need to install [this ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Eaplattner/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/).

To run with dGPU use `prime-run vlc`

Note :- If you have desktop optimus is gumarbage.